# Call to dialog from View class with static method

Tags: android, methods, view, static, android-context

I have a problem.
I would like call to Dialog from a View class. I use a public method. This is static. But when I use `... = new Dialog(getInstance());` or similar and then the app come there, it stops and the Log cat say me that argument  `context` is NULL.
I have tried several thing, and nothing. Always NULL. The static method are in Activity class.

Resume. When I try to put a context in a static method, program say me is NULL.
I dont need obligatory call from View if I can call in View class.

I put the code for more information.

Class Activity:

```
public class Control_Playing extends Activity{
   private static Control_Playing instance;

   public static Control_Playing getInstance() {
      if(instance == null)
            instance = new Control_Playing();
      return instance;
   }

....

  public static void runEmptyBox() {

    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getInstance());
    dialog.setTitle("asdf");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_1);
    TextView text = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    text.setText("asdf");
    dialog.show();
  }
```

Class View:

```
....
Control_Playing.runEmptyBox();
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating an Activity manually is bad and it will not work, so this is bad and the cause of your problem.

```
public static Control_Playing getInstance() {
   if(instance == null)
      instance = new Control_Playing();
   return instance;
}
```

You need to provide it an `Activity` context!

```
public static void showDialog(Context context){
    if(!(context instanceof Activity)){
        throw new new IllegalStateException("Context should be an activity");
    }
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog((Activity) context);
    ...
}
```

Do not share the same dialog between Activities, you should have a static construct method and keep a separate instance in each activity or you will be facing new problems!

Comment: Sorry, I am new. I dont understand very well. What `context` I pass? Is Your `showDialog`  my `runEmptyBox()`?  Thanks. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: yes, the method is the same, only different name. If you are displaying it from a view use the getContext() inside fragment use getActivity() inside Activity just use this and it should work

Comment: I can see the dialog now. Really, thank you very much.